# gas fee for 1 NFT > $ 10.000

Tags: nft, gas-price

Buy method in smart contract:

[image]

Gas fee > 10k
[image]

**Why so expensive?**

**EDIT**

My test:

```
    return Contract.deployed()
      .then(instance => {
        meta = instance;
        return meta.mint(account_one, 1, 'tokenURI', { from: account_one });
      })
      .then(() => {
          return meta.allowBuy(1, '20000000000000000', {from: account_one})
      })
      .then(() => {
          return meta.setApprovalForAll(account_two, true, {from: account_one})
      })
      .then((result) => {
          return meta.ownerOf(1)
      })
      .then((result) => {
          console.log('ownerOf before', result)
      })
      .then(() => {
          return meta.buy(1, {from: account_two, value: '20000000000000000'})
      })
      .then((result) => {
          return meta.ownerOf(1)
      })
      .then((result) => {
          console.log('ownerOf after', result)
      })
  });
```

Can I enable buy method without `approve`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This often happens when an error is thrown in the contract. Metamask will set the gasLimit to a very high value, showing ridiculous amounts of gas fees.
Check the code for possible errors, perhaps it's one of the first two require statements.

Comment: I updated the question putting the test I did and the result. It is accusing the value of the NFT in WEI that I defined for purchase.

Comment: Regarding the edit: when passing numbers, pass these as strings: meta.allowBuy(1, '20000000000000000', {from: account_one}) Also missing the return statement in that line.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what I do wrong. I need approve transfer to buy method works. I will update test in question to see. My question is: Can I enable buy method without "approve"?

Comment: It would be nice to have more context on what you're trying to do / have some contract code. I'm assuming this is some kind of marketplace. Then yes, you will have to make the user approve the marketplace contract to be able to transfer their NFT. If you didn't, anyone could just freely transfer your NFTs out of your wallet.

Comment: Its a simple NFT mint/buy contract extending ERC721. My "block way" is the price. When I mint some TOKEN, I set the price 0. If price == 0, can't buy/transfer the token. Owner of token can 'allowBuy' defining the new price and now others address can buy the token. But ok, I will use the approve like a order system, maybe works! Thanks Ian you help alot!

Comment: Another question: if I approve for some user and he take to long to buy, I can approve for another user? When I approve again for another user, the ERC-721 disable approve for old user?

Comment: Oh, I see `_tokenApprovals[tokenId] = to;`. So when I approve another user just replace the address in `_tokenApprovals`. Ok nice, perfect!